# copy specific files from a container using wildcard filename in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy specific files from a container in a Storage Account using an ADF pipeline.  lets say the container has the following files

- aa_aaa_01_yyyymmdd.csv
- aa_abb_01_yyyymmdd.csv
- aa_aaa_02_yyyymmdd.csv
- aa_aaa_03_yyyymmdd.csv
- aa_abb_02_yyyymmdd.csv
- ab_abc_01_yyyymmdd.csv

My pipeline has to copy all the files beginning with '**aa_aaa_**'. I tried using the * wildcard at the time of creating the source dataset - like "aa_aaa_*.csv" but didn't work; the validation fails.

please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use prefix option like below in copy activity
[image]

Comment: Doh! that was simple! thank you!